# Puppet file resource not resolving the source attribute

Tags: puppet, centos7, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

I have started to play with puppet 5 and for some reason the `source` attribute in the puppet `file` resource is not working. I have a simple manifest file in my puppet server which is as follows:

```
file {'/tmp/motd':
  source => '/tmp/motd',
}
```

On the agent, I issue:

```
puppet agent -t
```

which errors out as:

```
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/motd]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) file:/tmp/motd
```

The file `motd` exists on the puppet server in `/tmp/` directory

Any idea what might be going on here?

If I replace `source` attribute with `content => 'Testing 1 2 3'`, the `puppet agent -t` runs successfully creating a catalogue and I see the file `motd` on the client with the content `Testing 1 2 3`

Answer (score 2):

`source => '/tmp/motd'` refers the local file `/tmp/motd` on the Puppet node as source. To get a file from Puppet Master, use a `puppet://` URL. Per default all `files` directories of Puppet modules are accessible through `puppet:///modules/${module_name}/<filename>`.

Comment: **Note:** You could also use the [`file()` function](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/function.html#file) to return the contents of a file from disk.